# jq order by date Error - jq: error (at <stdin>:17): Cannot iterate over string ("2020-12-11...)

Tags: json, date, sorting, format, jq

Have some records in a json that I want to sort by date, but when trying it gives me the following error

*dates.json*

```
[  
  {
    "lastScalingAt": "2020-12-11T17:29:35.888Z",
    "lastConfigChangeAt": "2020-12-11T17:29:35.888Z"
  },
  {
    "lastScalingAt": "2020-12-11T17:29:38.655Z",
    "lastConfigChangeAt": "2020-12-11T17:29:38.655Z"
  },
  {
    "lastScalingAt": "2020-12-11T17:29:37.233Z",
    "lastConfigChangeAt": "2020-12-11T17:29:37.233Z"
  },
  {
    "lastScalingAt": "2020-12-08T20:42:09.990Z",
    "lastConfigChangeAt": "2020-03-30T16:23:59.682Z"
  }
]
```

I have tried with this:

```
jq '.[] | .lastConfigChangeAt | sort_by(.lastConfigChangeAt)' dates.json
```

**ERROR:**
jq: error (at :17): Cannot iterate over string ("2020-12-11...)

I've tried different ways but can't find what could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to sort by date

So, thanks to ISO 8601, the filter would be just that:

```
sort_by(.lastConfigChangeAt)
```

(That’s the entire jq program.)

Comment: If I just put the filter then it shows me another error

`jq '.[] | sort_by(.lastConfigChangeAt)' dates.json`

jq: error (at dates.json:18): Cannot index string with string "lastConfigChangeAt"

Comment: Why are you changing the program I showed? Drop the initial .[]

Comment: Perfect, it was my mistake: 

`jq ' sort_by(.lastConfigChangeAt)' dates.json`

Thanks a lot!!